# link spring integration channel to hornetq

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, hornetq

This seems to be simple but I can't work it out.

I am using spring-boot 1.2.2.  I have a hornet queue setup in `application.properties`:

```
spring.hornetq.mode=embedded
spring.hornetq.embedded.enabled=true
spring.hornetq.embedded.queues=myQueue
```

I have imported the `integration-context.xml` file.

```
@ImportResource("integration-context.xml")
```

And have defined the following activator:

```
<int:service-activator 
    input-channel="myQueue"
    ref="myEndpointImpl"
    method="send" > 
</int:service-activator>
```

But when I put a message on myQueue the `send` method is not fired.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HornetQ is JMS Broker and having that configuration you just provide an embedded mode with one `myQueue` definition, which is created by Boot on application start up. See more info in the Spring Boot [Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html#boot-features-hornetq).

Spring Integration allows to work with JMS through the appropriate [adapters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/jms.html).

So, if you are going to listen to that HornetQ `myQueue` using Spring Integration and do some further integration flow you really should configure `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` for that queue and go ahead with your `<service-activator>` etc. afterwards.

Feel free to ask more questions.